# DATE handiling from JSP to JAVA to PSQL and back

Tags: java, jsp, datetime

I am having a problem handling date variables when I write to PostgreSQL using JSP forms.  There has been some great tips but still can not get it right.  I believe that I am passing a String from JSP to JAVA where it is a Date "setter" and "getter" writing to PSQL on a "date without time zone" column.

Here is parts of the **JSP code** related to the Date:

.... (some code) ....

`SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");`

.... (mode code) ....

```
<%

if (action.equals("add")) {
  .
  .
  .

  newCampaign.setCampempDate(dateFormat.parse(request.getParameter("campemp")));

  newCampaign.add();
}  
%>
```

.... (more code) ....

```
               <input name="campemp" type="text" class="datePickBox" id="campemp"
 onBlur="javascript:checkFormat(this)" value="<%= defaultCampaign.getCampempDate() != null 
? dateFormat.format(defaultCampaign.getCampempDate()) : dateFormat.format(new 
java.util.Date()) %>" size=20>
```

.... (rest of code) ....

It is important to mention that on the input I am also using a calendar that passes the date with the correct format... this is another reason I am using a date field on the JSP side.

**On the JAVA side:**

.... (some code) ....

```
  private java.util.Date campemp= null; 

  private SimpleDateFormat userDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

... (more code) ...  ++ Set and Get ++

```
public void setCampempDate(java.util.Date aCampemp) {    
    this.campemp= aCampemp;
  }


 public java.util.Date getCampempDate() {
    return this.campemp;  
  }
```

... (more code) ... ++ LOAD ++

```
  public void load(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
   this.setId(rs.getLong("campkeydbid"));
    .
    .
  this.setCampempDate(rs.getDate("campemp"));
}
```

... (more code) ...  ++ WRITE TO DB ++

```
public boolean add() throws SQLException {
boolean success = false;
if (costingEnabled) {
  String call = "select " + getStoredProcedureMapper().getPrefix() + "_Add(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  DataSource ds = PoolMan.findDataSource("mydatabase");
  Connection conn = null;
  try {
    conn = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(call);
      .
      .
    pst.setTimestamp(10, new Timestamp(this.getCampempDate().getTime())); 
 ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
      .
      .
```

... (more code) ...

The "_Add" on the stored procedure is correct as it works if I "hardcode" the date on the pst.SetTimestamp

The error I am getting is the following:

*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "04/07/2012 19:12" to class "java.util.Date" for attribute "campemp": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager*

Any ideas on a workaround to parse the String to Date without affecting the DB date field and JSP input will be greatly appreciated.. thank you very much.

Regards,

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "04/07/2012 19:12" to class "java.util.Date" for attribute "campemp": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

You are passing `Date` in `String` in `04/07/2012 19:12` format so you need to use

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
```

From the code you posted, It seems you are using

```
private SimpleDateFormat userDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

as format in `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: Hi Jigar, thank you for your time in reviewing my code and the error... good spotting, I made the change to "dd/MMM/yyy HH:mm" and still gave me exactly the same error.  Any ideas ?

Comment: As said you need to change it to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`

Comment: thank you again, but still same error:


Jul 10, 2012 1:38:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert **string** "10-07-2012 13:38" to class "java.util.Date" for attribute "campemp": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

Comment: now in the setter of campemp you need to use DateFormatter with format `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm`

Comment: ok, but if I use the **parse.userDateFormat** like:     public void setCampemp(java.util.Date aCampemp) {    
    this.campemp = parse.userDateFormat(aCampemp);  then I need to change the "load" as it is a Date Field from the DB ??? so the getDate has to be changed too...

Comment: well to parse String to Date you need to use SimpleDateFormat with proper format, this comment answers  your question well

Comment: If you want to keep it in String you can, if you want to change it to Date you could also.

Comment: as far as I know I am using the correct format as per your previous post and get the same message except with the new format:   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "2012-07-10 15:59" to class "java.util.Date" for attribute "campemp": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

Comment: got it solved ! If I place the "LOAD" in before the Setters/Getters it worked !!